# Question about boarding pass scans

Tags: tickets, airport-security

For domestic flights in the US, when your boarding pass is scanned at the gate, does the gate agent make sure that pass was also scanned at security?

Comment: How could they? I might have one boarding pass from SFO-ORD and another from ORD-MSP. The second one certainly wouldn't have been scanned at security. And if I miss my connection and get issued a third boarding pass for a later flight, that one won't be scanned at security either.

Comment: That said, it sounds like there's a "real question" lurking beneath this one. It would help if you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: The question could be more clearly phrased as, "Can they tell if someone with that name has been through security at any point in the itinerary?" But you're right, if I buy separate one-way tickets that don't require me to leave the airport, there would be no way to cross-check that.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: The "real question" is "how can I avoid being price-gouged to change my itinerary when all I want to do is purchase an additional ticket that is fairly cheap, and skip the last leg of my original itinerary?" The airline wants to charge me $1000 to cancel the last leg of my flight so I can buy another ticket, and has also advised me that if I just go ahead and buy another and plan to not get on the plane for the last leg, their software will catch the duplicate booking and cancel my entire original itinerary.

Comment: That's an extremely different question. I suggest you ask that one :)

Comment: @Flyer1234 If it's the last leg, you can just skip it *if you don't check any baggage*.

Comment: If I just skip the last leg, I'll be stranded. I need to also purchase a new ticket to my final destination.

Comment: I think you need to ask the real question. Security scans are unlikely to be an issue. For example, you could have booked SFO-ORD on one airline, ORD-MSP on a separate ticket, and have printed your own boarding passes. Airline booking systems are much more likely to catch you.

Comment: Buy the second ticket with a small typo in your name and no system will notice. E.g. Johm instead of John.

Comment: They'll notice if you link both to the same frequent flyer account.

Comment: I'll use a different credit card, address, and no frequent flyer account. I did read an article about an airline trying to cancel a "Sarah Brown" because a "Sally Brown" was on the same flight and the duplicate booking software caught it, so I'm nervous about going with just a small typo. I have thought of using my nickname, rather than my full first name, and a small typo in my last name. Hopefully if they are on different flights, it won't be flagged?

Comment: On the same airline?  Put it this way, it's questionable if you even need to worry about this.  I have done this, skipped the end of one trip because I had a new one.  Nothing happened but, *I am not saying it won't so don't count on it.*  In fact, I recall stopping by the gate of the original flight to tell them I wasn't flying and the Agent just said "Thanks for letting us know!"

Comment: Yep, unfortunately it has to be the same airline. I've been told too many times that their software will catch the duplicate booking, and read articles about it happening, to feel secure just buying the second ticket. I'd consider waiting until I'm at the airport to buy the new ticket, but it's Christmas eve and the flight will likely be sold out.

Answer (score 3):

Except for one [experimental program](http://blog.tsa.gov/2011/10/catbpss-automatic-idboarding-pass.html), the two aren't connected.  CAT/BPSS is still being 'tested'. (**Note**, I'd totally forgotten about this so after following up, it appears that even CAT/BPSS is not real-time, it's merely a better document verification system.)

The scanners TSA currently uses validate some facets of the boarding pass, but are otherwise isolated.

Comment: Note that some non-US airports do have this though, eg the Conformance / Ready To Fly system used by BA at Heathrow (LHR) Terminal 5